# Como passar um objeto como parâmetro para o método de outra classe

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo uma agenda orientada a objetos e gravando em arquivo texto.

Estou encontrando o seguinte problema:

quando salvo um contato ele esta passando para outro objeto como se fosse um ponteiro

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace AgendaConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        private static bool sair = false;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Contato C = new Contato();
            Agenda A = new Agenda();

            if (A.Inicia())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Agenda Carregou!");
            }

            do
            {
                string resposta;
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("***AGENDA***");
                Console.WriteLine("1- Cadastrar");
                Console.WriteLine("2- Consultar");
                Console.WriteLine("3- Alterar");
                Console.WriteLine("4- Excluir");
                Console.WriteLine("5- Sair");
                resposta = Console.ReadLine();
                switch (resposta)
                {
                    case "1":

                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Nome:");
                        C.setNome(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.WriteLine("Email:");
                        C.setEmail(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.WriteLine("Telefone:");
                        C.setTelefone(Console.ReadLine());
                        A.adicionaContato(C);

                        Console.WriteLine("Pressione qualquer tecla para voltar ao menu.");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        break;
                    case "5":
                        sair = true;
                        break;

                }
            } while (!sair);
        }
    }
}
```

Na linha A.adicionaContato(C);

```
 public void adicionaContato(Contato C)
        {
            this.Contatos[posicao] = C;
            posicao++;
        }
```

acaba sempre replicando e adicionando na posição 0 e na que deveria mesmo adicionar duplicando o contato, na chamada adicionaContato ele ja esta com objeto na agenda.

Atualizando ...

```
classe Agenda

    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace AgendaConsole
{
    class Agenda
    {
        private Contato[] Contatos = new Contato[100];
        GravaArquivo G = new GravaArquivo();
        int posicao = 0;

        public bool Inicia()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                this.Contatos = G.CarregaAgenda();
            }
            return true;
        }

        public Contato Busca(string b)
        {
            Contato C = new Contato();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (b.Equals(this.Contatos[i].GetNome()))
                {
                    C = Contatos[i];
                }
            }
            return C;
        }

        public bool Salvar()
        {
            G.GravaAgenda(Contatos);

            return true;
        }

        public int buscaPosicao()
        {
            int cont = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (this.Contatos[i].GetNome().Equals(""))
                {
                    return cont;
                }
                else
                {
                    cont++;
                }
            }
            return cont;
        }

        public void adicionaContato(Contato C)
        {
            posicao=buscaPosicao();
            this.Contatos[posicao] = C;            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O problema não é este, e está em outro lugar, precisamo ver o que está fazendo. Na verdade este código nem tem cara de C#, mesmo sendo. Deve ter vários erros.

Comment: Onde está a classe Agenda classe agenda?

Comment: Tente disponibilizar os outros case do switch para verificar o código por completo.

Comment: @LuizAugusto Dei uma formatada e adicionei um complemento mínimo no código da sua pergunta para que ela faça algum sentido. Se você ainda deseja ajuda nessa questão adicione a sua classe `Agenda` e o restante do código relevante para a pergunta.

Comment: Adicionei o codigo da classe Agenda

Comment: Resolvi passando os atributos e não objeto todo